# ElasticsearchClient gives exception on composite aggregation

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying to set up a composite aggregation using the `ElasticsearchClient` since the `RestHighLevelClient` is deprecated. However I keep getting the following error:

`co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.ElasticsearchException: [es/search] failed: [x_content_parse_exception] [1:44] [composite] unknown field [name]`

Here is my setup and test code:

```
    @SneakyThrows
    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchClient elasticsearchClient() {

        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(
            AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(elasticUsername, elasticPassword));

        KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
        try (InputStream is = trustStoreResource.getInputStream()) {
            truststore.load(is, trustStorePassword.toCharArray());
        }
        SSLContextBuilder sslBuilder = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(truststore, null);
        final SSLContext sslContext = sslBuilder.build();

// Create the low-level client
        RestClient restClient =
            RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(elasticHostname, elasticPort, elasticScheme))
                .setHttpClientConfigCallback(
                    new HttpClientConfigCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(
                            HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) {
                            httpClientBuilder.disableAuthCaching();
                            return httpClientBuilder
                                .setSSLHostnameVerifier((s, sslSession) -> true)
                                .setSSLContext(sslContext)
                                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
                        }
                    })
                .build();

// Create the transport with a Jackson mapper
        ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(
            restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());


// And create the API client
        ElasticsearchClient client = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
        return client;
    }
```

Test

```
    @Test
    void testit() throws IOException {

      SearchRequest.Builder searchRequest =
          new SearchRequest.Builder() //
              .index(TestDocumentIndexUtils.WRITE_INDEX)
              .size(0);

      CompositeAggregation builtAggregation =
          new CompositeAggregation.Builder()
              .name("MyBuckets")
              .sources(
                  Arrays.asList(
                      Maps.mutable.of(
                          "uuids",
                          new CompositeAggregationSource.Builder()
                              .terms(p -> p.name(UNIQUE_UUIDS).field("uuid"))
                              .build())))
              .size(20)
              .build();
      searchRequest.aggregations(builtAggregation.name(), builtAggregation._toAggregation());

      SearchResponse<Object> searchResponse =
          elasticsearchClient.search(searchRequest.build(), Object.class);
    }
```

Elasticsearch and client lib are both 7.16.3

Comment: Can you print out the generated query?

Comment: @Val toString doesn't seem to be supported for this library. All I get is SearchRequest@742747